# C# Custom Setter Event or Inherited Setter

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to have a setter inherit from "something" that would allow me to run some code each time a setter is invoked for a particular base class and it's inheritors?

What I want to do is have a boolean flag on my base class called IsValid. I will set this boolean to true after validating an object, then if any setter is invoked after validation, I want the setter to change the IsValid flag to false.

I don't want to have to write this logic into every setter.

Comment: The problem is that C# doesn't have such specific feature and also lacks some meta-programming capacities that would allow to nearly automate the example given below by Brian Rudolph. One .NET language capable of such tricks is Boo, where you can define a MetaAttribute to expand to the equivalent of that example code. Would look like:

[ValidatingProperty]
private property as int

And would generate something like this C# code:
private int property;
public int Property { get { return property; } set { Invalidate(); property = value;}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking for some version of [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (AOP).  You have a common operation that you want to perform across all properties, without implementing it in every case.

I'm not sure what the choices really are for AOP in C#, but one I have used before is [Spring.Net AOP](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html).  What it will do is wrap your class in a dynamically created wrapper which will intercept all calls to your properties and then allow you to implement some common logic to execute.

Comment: Yeah, it's called a TransparentProxy.

Comment: Thanks Chris, In fact, I am using NHibernate, so wrapping a class yet again is a bad option I'm sure. Do you know if NHibernate has any existing events I can connect to?

Comment: I wouldn't know if there is a hook alreayd provided, but I wouldn't assume that using a wrapper would have too much cost.  Because your logic in the interceptor will be really simple, it should mostly be the cost of an extra function call on every property set.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't directly possible in the language.

However, one way to handle this is to using something like [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  If your base class specifies that it implements this interface, your subclasses should also raise PropertyChanged events.  The base class could use this to track changes and validate the object.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the PostSharp to add this functionality or maybe this thread at StructureMap
http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users/browse_thread/thread/fbadf4c2779ab8ed?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If the properties in question are virtual, you can override them to provide the notification and call the base class' implementation to ensure the "set" goes through.

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing this in C# without code in every setter is through a TransparentProxy. It is a bit cumbersome, but it can be made to appear invisible to the coder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you could do is create a virtual method in the abstract class and call it from the property setter. Then you can override it in the inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue all the time... so i use a pattern like this:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar1
   {
      get{return this._Bar1;}
      set{this.SafeSet(ref this._Bar1, value);}
   }public string _Bar1;

   public int Bar2
   {
      get{return this._Bar2;}
      set{this.SafeSet(ref this._Bar2, value);}
   }public int _Bar2;

   protected virtual SafeSet<T> (ref T local, T val)
   {
      if(local != val)
      {
         local = val;
         //whatever other post-processing you want
      }
   }
}
```